# Foreground extraction with zebra background

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, background-subtraction

I am trying to classifiy grayscale images but I need to focus on a specific object on each image.
I would like to segment the object but the targeted object has the same color than the background.
And the background is like a zebra color, successive dark grey/light grey lines.
I have already performed some algorothms developed by OpenCv but no interesting results.

Do you have any ideas of DL techniques tu subtract the background or extract the targeted object ?
Or an image processing algorithm to "highlight" the lines ?

I have a set of images with the targeted object and another one without that object (like the background). Images from different sets are very similar but not exactly the same.

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you know the "clean" background?

Comment: No, I have only these 2 types of images : the first is the "template" without the object and the second one is the basic image with the object that I want to segment

Comment: that template is probably what I meant, so you always do have that; why don't you simply subtract one from the other image and work on the difference?

Comment: I mean I'am trying to extract the wire but on the black background the wire is also black. When I subtract one with the other, this part of the wire is "lost"

Comment: yes, but you can just as well extrapolate the missing part from the image with or without background; also, the dark of the needle seems to be sufficiently different from the dark of your background

Comment: @floriandaniel, If you need to classify the object and can use Deep Learning, why not just let a Deep Learning model classify the image?